# Is the function $d(x,y) = \frac{\|x-y\|}{\|x\|\|y\|}$ a metric?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

$d$ is defined for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2 - \{0\}$.

It's clear that $d(x,y) = 0 \iff x=y$ and $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$

I am having issues with triangle inequality. I couldn't find a counterexample for which the triangle inequality doesn't hold. So I tried to prove it.

What I have so far is:
$$d(x,z) =  \frac{\|x-z\|}{\|x\|\|z\|} \leq  \frac{\|x-y\|}{\|x\|\|z\|}
+  \frac{\|y-z\|}{\|x\|\|z\|} $$

I'm stuck here.
I appreciate if you could give me some hints.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like there is a typo on the right side of the inequality. You want some $y$'s in the denominators.

Comment: @JeremyBrazas That looks intentional. Santos is claiming that the inequality is true (which it is), not that that is what they want to show.

Comment: $0\not\in\mathbb{R}^{2}.$

Comment: @WillR $0$ is a common notation for the zero vector in whatever vector space we're talking about.

Comment: @Snow Ah yes, I incorrectly read it as the main claim.

Comment: What you wrote implies the result you want provided $\| z \| \geq \| y \|$. What if $\| y \| > \| z \|$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Identify the set of non-zero vectors in $\Reals^{2}$ with the set of non-zero *complex* numbers. The Euclidean norm corresponds with the complex modulus, so if $x$ and $y$ are non-zero, then
$$
\frac{\|x - y\|}{\|x\|\, \|y\|}
  = \left\|\frac{x - y}{xy}\right\|
  = \left\|\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{x}\right\|.
$$
That is, $d$ corresponds to the ordinary Euclidean distance after a bijection (the complex reciprocal map), and therefore satisfies the triangle inequality.

Comment: It's striking that the argument doesn't seem to generalize in an obvious way to vectors in arbitrary dimension. The best I could find along those lines was to consider the bijection$$f(x, y) = \left(\frac{x}{\|x\|\, \|y\|}, \frac{y}{\|x\|\, \|y\|}\right)$$of the set of ordered pairs of non-zero vectors, for which, if $\delta(x, y) = \|x - y\|$, we have $d(x, y) = \delta \circ f(x, y)$. After a few minutes' thought, I didn't see way of deducing the triangle inequality for $d$. If anyone manages this (especially if there's a slick proof I overlooked), I'd be interested to see the argument.

Comment: For $\mathbb{R}^d\setminus \{0\}$, this argument works if $d\in \{1,2,4\}$ (since the multiplication of quaternions isn't commutative, write the expression as $\lVert x^{-1}\rVert\cdot \lVert x-y\rVert\cdot \lVert y^{-1}\rVert$). Of course we can get the $d = 3$ case by embedding into $\mathbb{R}^4$. But it's useful to recall that if you have something involving the norms of only two points/vectors, you are essentially in a two-dimensional situation. So for general $d > 1$, take a plane containing $x$ and $y$, and isometrically map it to $\mathbb{C}$. Done by the case $d = 2$.

Comment: @Daniel: That's the slick proof I overlooked. Thanks! :)

Comment: Err, not quite. For the triangle inequality we get a third point, so we may need a three-dimensional subspace. Make it "Done by the case $d = 4$".

Comment: @AliTaghavi Yes, this metric induces the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^d\setminus \{0\}$. For a given $x$, we have $$\frac{2}{3\lVert x\rVert^2}\lVert x-y\rVert \leqslant d(x,y) \leqslant \frac{2}{\lVert x\rVert^2}\lVert x-y\rVert$$ for $y \in B_{\lVert x\rVert/2}(x)$.